# Packing open source software alongside a commercial software

Tags: legal, commercial

I'm creating a commercial web-app and to avoid compatibility issues between operating systems and browser I want to pack a portable chromium alongside my software and to use it to run the app. GPL2 states:

"b) You must cause any work that you distribute or publish, that in whole or in part contains or is derived from the Program or any part thereof, to be licensed as a whole at no charge to all third parties under the terms of this License."

So I assume mine usage too is an infringement of the license correct? **If so are there any alternatives?**

Comment: Do you link your code to Chromium or modify it in any way? Or are you just distributing it along with your application and encouraging customers to use it as the web browser used to run the client side of you app?

Comment: Pack both of them together and open my code in Chromium without modifying Chromium code.

Comment: Based on the scant information you provided, it does sound like a violation of the GPL unless you are offering the source code of your own program free of charge.  The remedy is to use a different library that is not GPL, or write your own.  Note that the open-source Chromium browser to which you refer does not appear to be licensed under the GPL.  Do more research.

Comment: @RobertHarvey, it depends what the OP means by "pack". If they are simply in the same installer and chromium just launches the app, then even the GPL, with it's highly infectious viral licence, can't claim ownership of the app. If "pack" means linking in some way, so that the app runs chromium, then it could well be a violation.

Comment: @DavidArno: It also depends on what the OP means by "GPL."  So far, he hasn't mentioned any software that has that license, including Chromium.